# How to highlight a table cells when you click on another cell?

Tags: c#, wpf, xceed-datagrid

Good day!

I have a grid with two logical subgrids,  the first subgrid have links with second subgrid (at logical things,not wpf), but i want to get this:

When i click on cell at first subgrid => then another cells(at second subgrdid) wich links of cell at first subgrid - make background color change.

I can get link from cell1 and another cells(at logic), but i dont  know how :

1. detect what cell was clicked  (maybe DataRowsChanged?)
2. how to change background color at linked cells?

   Can you tell me how to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Post your sample code here.

Comment: You can achive that by using DataTriggers. You'll have to set your custom style to [DataGrid.CellStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.cellstyle.aspx) property.